# Make sure Column B = a certain value when Column A is Null - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to make sure that when Column A is NULL (in csv), or NaN (in dataframe), Column B is "Cash".

I've tried this:

```
check = df[df['A'].isnull()]['B']
check = check.to_string(index=False)
if "Cash" not in check:
    print "Column A Fail"
else:
    print "Column A Pass!"
```

But it is not working.

any suggestions?

I also need to make sure that it doesn't treat '0' as NaN

Answer (score 3):

Use `loc` to assign where `A` is null.

```
df.loc[df['A'].isnull(), 'B'] = 'Cash'
```

---

***example***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=[np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan],
        B=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    ))

print(df)

     A  B
0  NaN  a
1  1.0  b
2  2.0  c
3  NaN  d
```

Then do

```
df.loc[df['A'].isnull(), 'B'] = 'Cash'
print(df)

     A     B
0  NaN  Cash
1  1.0     b
2  2.0     c
3  NaN  Cash
```

---

**check if all `B` are `'Cash'` where `A` is null***

```
(df.loc[df.A.isnull(), 'B'] == 'Cash').all()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! my goal is not to assign 'Cash', but rather to make sure that it's already there as a quality check

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

> my goal is not to assign 'Cash', but rather to make sure that it's
>   already there as a quality check

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]:
     A     B
0  NaN     a
1  1.0     b
2  2.0     c
3  NaN  Cash

In [41]: df.query("A != A and B != 'Cash'")
Out[41]:
    A  B
0 NaN  a
```

or using boolean indexing:

```
In [42]: df.loc[df.A.isnull() & (df.B != 'Cash')]
Out[42]:
    A  B
0 NaN  a
```

**OLD answer:**

Alternative solution:

```
In [23]: df.B = np.where(df.A.isnull(), 'Cash', df.B)

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
     A     B
0  NaN  Cash
1  1.0     b
2  2.0     c
3  NaN  Cash
```

another solution:

```
In [31]: df = df.mask(df.A.isnull(), df.assign(B='Cash'))

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
     A     B
0  NaN  Cash
1  1.0     b
2  2.0     c
3  NaN  Cash
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! my goal is not to assign 'Cash', but rather to make sure that it's already there as a quality check

Comment: @NazariyKurdoba, so you want to select those rows which __don't__ satisfy this condition - right?

Answer (score 1):

According to logic rules, P=>Q is (not P) or Q. So

```
(~df.A.isnull()|(df.B=="Cash")).all()
```

check all the lines.